# Otsu segmentation makes mistakes

Tags: python, opencv, dataset, conv-neural-network

I am following this [article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/344249077_Flower_Identification_and_Classification_using_Computer_Vision_and_Machine_Learning_Techniques) as reference but I am working with a butterfly dataset.

I have applied the Otsu technique for segmentation based on this [implementation](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/09/image-segmentation-algorithms-with-implementation-in-python/) . Sadly, it does some clear mistakes like the one I show here:

[image]

is there any way to improve this preprocessing? I would like to get a result like the one in the flower article (Fig 1).

Thanks

Comment: Your image is not bimodal. It has lots of dark, medium and light shades of gray (so tai-modal). So Otsu thresholding does not apply since it works on bimodal images.

Comment: that's what I read in this discussion https://www.researchgate.net/post/How-to-improve-the-Otsu-segmentation-results-and-how-to-extract-the-the-region-of-interest-lesion-in-my-case-after-segmentation but which technique should I use then? or any way to fix the requirements for otsu?

Comment: Instance segmentation neural networks are appropriate for such uncontrolled real world data, but collecting training data is very hard/expensive. Give superpixel segmentation techniques a try, but might introduce some more challenges.

Comment: Look as not controlled environment you should try deep learning techniques as Mask R CNN